# Find the maximum hyperrectangle contained in a set of points

Tags: mathematical-optimization, computational-geometry, algorithm

I have a question similar to this one ( [Find the largest rectangular block satisfying some condition without iterating explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161332/find-the-largest-rectangular-block-satisfying-some-condition-without-iterating-e)). but in my case I have a multidimensional (up to 6 dimensions) binary array and I want to find the largest [hyperrectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperrectangle) (by volume, i.e. product of dimensions) that contains only 1's.

For example, in 3D, the data would look like:

```
    data = Table[If[i - j - k <= -1, 1, 0]
       , {i, 11}
       , {j, 11}
       , {k, 11}
    ];
```

[image]

Comment: You also want to do this without iterating explicitly? Or you're only interested in a solution to finding the smallest encompassing hyperrectangle?

Comment: An algorithm that does the job without iterating explicitly should be faster, and I want to get an answer within the limit of 2 hours tops.

Comment: I don't know the exact implementation of `Max` and `Min` to say whether they iterate the full list or not, but they're likely to be the fastest means of finding their respective extremes in a list. If you take your list of coordinates and find the `Max` and `Min` in each dimension, you should be able to use those to construct your vertices (assuming you're interested in the location of the hyperrectangle). If all you want is the volume than it's just the product of `Abs[Max-Min]` in each dimension.